# Hibernate won't add Discriminator Column to Table

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I previously had this entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SOMETABLE")
@AccessType("field")
public class SomeEntity implements java.io.Serializable {
```

Then I changed it to this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SOMETABLE")
@AccessType("field")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DISCRIMINATOR", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 20)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "Some")
public class SomeEntity implements java.io.Serializable {
```

and I added some subclasses

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "SomeOther")
public class SomeOtherEntity extends SomeEntity {
```

Hibernate does not add a new Discriminator column to SOMETABLE for rows that were previously there.

It is adding other new columns I have defined in SomeEntity. @ForceDiscriminator didn't seem to do anything. How do I get the column to show up in a clean way?

Comment: did you mean Discriminator value for the rows that were previously there

Comment: Do you want the Hibernate to add the discriminator column with appropriate values to the rows which are already present in the database before you defined the inheritance?

Comment: yes to both of your questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered my own question. Hibernate can't add a new not-null column and the Discriminator is a not-null column. A way to fix it is to add columnDefinition to specify a default

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DISCRIMINATOR", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, columnDefinition = "varchar default 'SomeOther'" , length = 20)
```

So this would default all the rows that don't have the discriminator to be of the type SomeOtherEntity.

However, this is not a good solution because it forces you to use varchar which may be database specific. So thanks Hibernate for not allowing to change a declared entity into a superclass.